# Getting value from a servlet to insert into DB using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, servlets

I Have a Login page which is a JSP and a servlet where i get the username from the Login page using request.getParameter. I now want to insert that username into a mysql DB using hibernate. In my hibernate program, how i can access the username???

My servlet is - 
public class LoginPage extends HttpServlet {

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException {  
    String username= request.getParameter("username");
    System.out.println("Hi  " + username);

}
```

}

and Hibernate program is-

public class HibernateTest {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Login name = new Login();       
    name.setUserName("");//////This line shows error. What should be inside ""
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(name);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
```

}

The marked line shows error when i run.What should be inside "". How can i retrieve username from the servlet???

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but if you need to ask such a question, you're not ready to use servlets, and even less ready to use Hibernate, which is a complex beast to master. Learn basic programming stuff first like "what is a method, and how to call it?".

Comment: Hi JB Nizet , I did not get exactly what you wanted to convey or if u exactly got my issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any issue in your code. If both are working fine, you just need to move everything to your servlet class:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException {  
    String username= request.getParameter("username");

    Login name = new Login();       
    name.setUserName(username);
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(name);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Of course, in a robust application we are going to add layers and apply some design patterns...

Comment: Thanks Yori, I tried that way it works. I was just wondering if keeping servlet and hibernate separate i can achieve the same. But this helps as well..

Comment: It is suggested to treat thinks in different layers. You can use servlets to get parameters from your JSPs. Then, another class only to deal with data persistency. Try reading some books about "Design Patters", it will move your coding mentality to the next level.